# Redemption give exception in m/c do not have outlook or have outlook express

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I have created an application that access Exchange Server using Redemption.It works fine in my machine ( I have outlook 2007 at my machine) but when I run same application in other system containing outlook express it gives me the following error:

Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID{ } from the IClassFatory failed due to the following error:80004005.

NOTE: This error comes while creating the new RDOSession object.

Please tell me the reason and what should I do to achieve this.

Many Thanks for the solution in advance.

Here is the code:

```
 Redemption.RDOSession rdoSession = new Redemption.RDOSession();
rdoSession.Logon(OL_USER, OL_SERVER,false,false,null,null);
 MessageBox.Show("STORE KIND: " + rdoSession.Stores.DefaultStore.StoreKind.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Store Name: : " + rdoSession.Stores.DefaultStore.Name);

                foreach (Redemption.RDOReminder reminder in rdoSession.Stores.DefaultStore.Reminders)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Reminders: : "+ reminder.Caption);
                }
```

===========================UPDATED================================

Yes to access Excnahge Server I have to call method LogonExchangeMailbox() instead of Log On but the problem is on creating the new instance of RDOSession it gives the exception and this exception comes in m/c where outlook express is installed but working fine where outlook 2007 is installed.

EXCEPTION :

```
"creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID{ } from the IClassFatory failed due to the following error:80004005."
```

Answer (score 0):

The Logon method uses an outlook profile which you dont have on that machine .. you should use the LogonExchangeMailbox as that create a temp profile for you ..

**Update**

Have you check that the registartion worked on your express machine ? might be a good idea to re-register redemption.dll

Comment: yes i have register redemption.dll in express m/c but still find the error.

Comment: Try using RDo inside a VBA envioment such as word vbs etc. as I sound like that the registration is screwed or the interop is not happy .. how are you distributing your app ? is a console app ?